# Windows settings UI file associations section crashs while explorer keeps restarting as soon as PDF files are involved

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, pdf, foxit-reader, windows-10-v1903

Some days ago Windows showed me a message that there was detected a problem with Foxit Reader which caused Windows to select Microsoft Edge as default PDF reader instead.

Foxit detected the change and asked me to reset it. I acknowledged and Foxit did its job but nothing changed. Thats because of a new security feature in Windows 10 blocking file associations via registry setup as I learned now.
But at this moment I let Foxit try it again but nothing happened. I then set Foxit as default app for .pdf in Windows settings UI and it worked.

Now my explorer run crazy, every time it should display a PDF file it restarts and reloads all files so that I am unable to click on anything.

In Windows settings UI the default apps section for file associations loads for ages and then closes itself. Only the by program section shows results but also gets crazy as soon as Foxit gets selected.

`sfr /scannow` found errors and repaired them, so was `dism /online...` , but nothing changed.

Comment: That can be messy because Windows Explorer is completely built in. Go to Nirsoft.net and download Shell Menu View-x64. Set it up and run it. Look for yellow sections indicating bad shell extensions and delete these. Look at red extensions and make sure you know why these are there. Uncommon apps cause red shell extensions but are otherwise harmess

Comment: Sorry @John for stealing your time. Wasn't expecting someone responding this fast! But you're right. Windows Explorer is so deep rooted that this was only luck to find. Thank you for your try helping me with that anyways!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue today morning and post it here because i couldn't find anything on the Internet the last days and hope that someone with the same issue will find this here.

As the problems only came up when PDFs were involved, I looked up the registry entry for the file association although Microsoft TechNet was promising me that there isn't anything to be done there as they are neglecting every change there by reseting it to defaults to force everybody using the Windows settings UI. (I understand the security reasons behind this but the popups if you are really sure to unselect Microsoft apps are really annoying there.)

What I found was a folder structure just like for the other file type associations (I was looking at .xlsx in my case). The only strange thing was the empty UserChoice subdirectory. But as other file associations didnt have this subdirectory either I was not interested in it.

*Btw: There's a way calculating the hash that Windows uses for checking if the change was made by the settings UI or not. So the security aspect is thrown away in my eyes.*

In my despair I hoped that deleting the subdirectory may help reseting it to defaults. The deletion process stopped at the previously mentioned UserChoice folder because I didnt had the rights to delete it. At a closer look I was confused that only this folder had absolutly no rights set. So I just set myself as full rights owner and Ta-da: all well known groups like SYSTEM and other ones appeared. Also new keys were inserted in the folder. I deleted it nevertheless as all the other subfolders were already gone too.
After that I entered Windows settings UI file associations section and it displayed all entries after a few seconds. Microsoft Edge was selected for .pdf, which makes sense as the registry was reseted to defaults as intended. I selected Foxit and it succeeded.

My explorer is again working like nothing ever happened.